# iOS dev: UILabel (CALayer) is taking increasing memory

Tags: objective-c, xcode, memory, uilabel, release

So when I run my app along with the Allocation Instrument, I found that there's a "UILabel (CALayer)" that is taking much memory and it is increasing to over 100 #persistent.

But when I scroll down, I also noticed another UILabel without the parenthesis CALayer.

So my question is what's the difference between these too, and how to properly release the UILabels? I use storyboard to initialize the UILabels and use code to set the graphics. I tried to nil all the Labels in ViewDidDiappear method and add autorelease, but it didn't work. Will get the labels out from storyboard and init by code solve this problem? I'm just not sure what is the CALayer means here.

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: `CALayer` is `CoreAnimation Layer`, which all `UIView` and its sub class will be in `CALayer`. That is why it can be animated easily. I have the same issue with you. Looking for the solution now.